# relative negative radian bearings to cartesian coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have Python code to go from polar to Cartesian if the angles are all positive from 0 to 2 pi.

```
x = distance * np.cos(angle)
y = distance * np.sin(angle)
```

So given a certain bearing in radians, that would go where `angle` is and the distance in that direction is `distance`.
But how do I deal with bearings given to me in negative radians?

Comment: If it's negative just add $2\pi$ to get a positive value for the same angle.

Comment: That's so cool.

Comment: Or do nothing different at all, since Python will be perfectly happy to compute the sine and cosine of a negative angle.